# Globally change mod_proxy reset time?

Tags: mod-proxy, jboss

Im running a server configuration where apache(win 2.4) is acting as a load balancer for a 2 jboss servers. The load balancer is running unadvertised balancer, and my two servers are pointing towards it through mod_cluster configuration.

I am getting a 60s timeout from mod_proxy when connection is lost. Now my understanding is this 60s is from mod_proxy

> AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for () for 60s

Is there anyway to change this value without configuring ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse? Some sort of global setting?

My config is -

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

# MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS
# Adjust to you hostname and subnet.
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 12.34.56.123:1234
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  ExtendedStatus On

  <VirtualHost 12.34.56.123:1234>
    <Location />
    Require ip 10.
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 60
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    EnableMCPMReceive
    AllowDisplay On
    ServerAdvertise Off

    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Allow from all
    </Location>

    <Location "/server-status">
        SetHandler server-status
        Allow from all
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well the default for the mod proxy timeout is to use the value of the global Timeout of apache.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I ended up checking the source and it could only be set by configuring mod_proxy. I think the error might be a red herring as mod_cluster monitors the proxy differently